# Google Cloud Server Email Forwarding

Tags: email, dns-zone, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud server with Cloud DNS working for my domain and IIS hosted website.

I need email for my domain to be forwarded, i.e. for john@myCloudServerDomain.com to go to my existing account john@gmail.com.

I tried putting an MX record in as per https://cloud.google.com/dns/what-is-cloud-dns but my emails aren't coming through.

What's the best option to get email from my domain?:

- Set Cloud DNS to forward emails
- Set GoDaddy email up? (I bought the domain from them but the nameservers point to Google Cloud, I imagine this means I cannot use their email service..)
- A better 'standard practice' option I haven't thought of?

Comment: Buy Google Apps?

Comment: @Michael Hampton, can you please elaborate how google apps would help me, does Google have a mail server I can quickly setup? I googled for 'Google Apps email' but of course this is a very generic term and comes up with Android apps, gmail etc. and nothing specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks for the comments guys. I didn't want to setup a mail server and have that drama, nor did I want to pay for email.

I've solved this by setting GoDaddy's name servers back to point to GoDaddy, and setting my VM's static IP as the A record in GoDaddy's management tool. This allows my website to load using DNS to resolve my domain and I can use the free GoDaddy email forwarders/accounts and I no longer have a requirement to use the Google Cloud DNS.

Comment: Incredibly annoying that Google Cloud DNS doesn't offer what 99% of the competition does.  I feel like I want compensation for time spent setting up DNS in their system.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a mail server. In the same way you use **IIS** as a web server, you need a mail server to accept mail on your behalf.

GoDaddy has mail plans:

https://www.godaddy.com/email/email-hosting.aspx

Alternatively you could use Google Apps for Work (similar pricing):

https://apps.google.com/

Once you have set up a business email hosting account, you will need to update the MX records (and possibly other records) at Google Cloud DNS as per the email provider's instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! First, you need an MX record that looks like this:

.domainname.com

0 smtp.securecerver.net.

10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.

That routes the mail traffic back to Godaddy. This is the missing piece believe it or not. You need to add this TXT record:

.domainname.com

"v=spf1 mx include:secureserver.net -all"   (quotes required)